# Cannot send Email :( - The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: c#, ssl

```
    public static void SendEmail(StringBuilder sb) {
            string mailbody = string.Empty;
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient("aaaaa.com");
            smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "pwd");
            //smtpServer.Port = 587;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            smtpServer.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            smtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            mail.From = new MailAddress("bbbb.com");
            mail.To.Add("ccccc.com");
            mail.Subject = string.Format("test");
            mailbody = sb.ToString();
            mail.Body = mailbody;
            smtpServer.Send(mail);
```

//everytime I get this error message and how to handle this, is this a security breach to bypass ssl in a company ? kindly advise the best way to handle this code and to send email.
            }

Comment: try with smtpServer.EnableSsl = false;

Comment: Have your network uses proxy server? AFAIK `EnableSsl = false` doesn't work for Gmail. Try using export and import certificate with MMC instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17885892/6378815.

Comment: @Nikhil.Patel thanks, .EnableSsl = false worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Unexpected “ The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39024611/3424212)

> ...tell StmpClient to ignore security with

```
client.EnableSsl = true;
```